# What is that on Athena's chest?

Tags: greek, myth-identification, athena, goddesses, maiden-goddesses

[image]

In this statue there is something what looks like a face on Athena's chest. I have seen it on some other statues of Athena. 
What is it?  Is there a myth behind it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not clear from your picture, but the face is most probably a [Gorgoneion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgoneion), a recurring element of Athena's iconography:

> In Ancient Greece, the Gorgoneion (Greek: Γοργόνειον) was a special apotropaic amulet showing the Gorgon head, used most famously by the Olympian deities Athena and Zeus: both are said to have worn the gorgoneion as a protective pendant. It was assumed, among other godlike attributes, as a royal aegis to imply divine birth or protection, by rulers of the Hellenistic age, as shown, for instance, on the Alexander Mosaic and the Gonzaga Cameo.
>
> <sub>Source: Wikipedia contributors. (2018, June 16). Gorgoneion. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 21:22, February 5, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gorgoneion&oldid=846161112</sub>

The ever-so-helpful theoi.com has tons of information on the mythology of the [Gorgons](https://www.theoi.com/Pontios/Gorgones.html), if you wish to know more about them. We also happen to host some very [interesting questions about Medusa and her sisters](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medusa?sort=votes&pageSize=30) on this site.